# How to communicate between mobile with PC?

Tags: java, data-transfer

I am developing a program that is used to communicate between a mobile and a pc. I don't have any idea how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you would need to write two separate pieces of software:

1) A Server

2) A Client

I would suggest you install the server on the PC and the client on the phone.

The client would establish a TCP connection to the server and would be able to send messages reliably. Upon receiving the messages from the client (phone) your server (pc) will act accordingly.

You can refer to the java documentation to find two simple samples about creating TCP servers and clients and these should be very helpful. [Example Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bluetooth of the mobile, and develop a Server in java for your pc.

I have done this process.